# One larger site OR a medium and a one subsite?

Tags: seo, ecommerce

I've build two webshops:
**A** - Sells watch straps only
**B** - Sells watches, tools for watches, more watches and more watch related objects.

We've come at a point where a choice has to be made and we're having difficulty deciding which option is the better one:

**Option 1:** Leave it as is (for the user). Make the appearance of two stops (A ánd B)
**Option 2:** Make the watchstraps a part of the site B, resulting in 1 larger shop

I don't really know how to decide which is the better and/or why. Both sites are very similar (one is purple with orange, the other orange with purple), so merging them won't confuse too many people.

**I'd like to know how to resolve this issue, how do I decide?** Offcourse is income the primary reason for these sites to exist, so SEO is muy importante.

---

For the replies: Thank you. I'm going to decide soon, maybe someone has something important to add. +1-ed for good info :)

Comment: Why opinionbased? Im looking for abstract methods to decide the better (in my situation).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vote two for one site: The reasons are simple.

Pros:

- Less work maintaining two sites.
- Less cost maintaining two sites.
- Watch straps should integrate well into other site topically.
- SEO would be stronger for watch straps without diluting SEO for other
  site.
- One stop shopping for someone who needs a strap and something else or
  vice versa.
- Only one site/shop to pay attention to, take orders from, process
  orders from, etc.
- Opportunity to change colors. (Just kidding!)

Cons:

- Would have to (possibly) 301 redirect links to straps domain to other
  domain for a  period.
- Would take some work to save work.

I am always in favor of simplicity. It makes sense from a business perspective too. This is a good time in SEO history to take this leap too. Google seems to like natural order these days and combining both sites seems to fit this idea.

Answer (score 1):

One site.

Become one stop. Having two sites may make them look and behave differently. Some visitors may even learn to dislike one over the other. Some may think they are two different companies.

Become that one "go to" site.